# Mail isn't sent after local site registration

Tags: user-registration, local-installation, email

I installed a new WP site on local machine with wamp server.
When a new user registers it gets the "registration successful" message but a mail with the password is never sent. Also checked the junk folder.
What can be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your local setup since Wamp does NOT come with mail server. But you can configure the STMP settings of PHP to point to another server in your LAN which runs an SMTP server, or to the SMTP server of your ISP.

this thread has an example of how to set it up:
http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,31302,70969

Comment: @Bainternet , after configuring the mail server do I need to configure anything on the wordpress installation?

Comment: Nope just configure the mail settings and you are done.

Comment: @Bainternet , I don't know how but the SMTP value in php.ini of the wamp server is already set to be my ISP's smtp server and the port is 25.  
Still, the mails from wordpress are not arriving.

Comment: @Bainternet , just to be sure, I added in one of the pages php template this call: `mail('me@ISPdomain.com','test subject','test body');` with my real mail address, of course.
I got the following response: "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Relaying not allowed. Please use SMTP Authentication."

Comment: can you paste your php.ini (the smtp part)

Comment: @Bainternet , sure - `SMTP = mail.013.net.il
smtp_port = 25`

Comment: Try adding your authentication details `auth_username = example_username@example.com
auth_password = example_password` right under it.

Comment: @Bainternet , I still get the same message. 
But I managed with the 'WP-Mail-SMTP' plugin.
Only instead of sending through the ISP I used my online websites host. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that this isn't really a WordPress issue, but actually an problem with how you're setup for mail on your local machine / dev environment.

You can install a 'dummy' SMTP server on your local dev machine that allows you some independence from your environment. I often work at client sites where access to port 25 is tightly controlled, and using MockSMTP is very helpful for testing notification emails

For OS X: [MockSMTP](http://mocksmtpapp.com/)

For Windows: [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/)